# JavaSpaces-like patterns in Ignite

Tags: java, ignite

I've used GigaSpaces in the past and I'd like to know if I can use Ignite in a similar fashion.  Specifically, I need to implement a master-worker pattern where one set of process writes objects to the in-memory data grid and another set reads those objects, does some processing, and possibly writes results back to the grid.  One important GigaSpaces/JavaSpaces feature I need is leasing.  If I write an object to the space and it isn't picked up within a certain time period, it should automatically expire and I should get some kind of notification.

Is Apache Ignite a good match for this use case?

Comment: How about you play around with it and let us know?

Comment: I don't see that it supports the JavaSpaces API.  If you don't feel like answering my questions, don't.

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked with GigaSpaces before. What you are looking for is perhaps "continuous queries" in Ignite. That would allow create a filter for a specific predicate I.e. Checking a field of a new object being written to the grid. Once the filter is evaluated it will trigger a listener that can execute the logic you require and write results or changes back to the grid. You can create as many of these queries as desired and create chains. Similar to the "notification container" in gigaspaces. And as you would expect you can control the thread pools for this separately.

As for master worker pattern, you can configure client Ignite nodes to be written the the data and server nodes to store and process the data. You can even use other client nodes as remote listeners for data changes as you mentioned.

Check these links:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with GigaSpaces before. What you are looking for is perhaps "continuous queries" in Ignite. That would allow create a filter for a specific predicate I.e. Checking a field of a new object being written to the grid. Once the filter is evaluated it will trigger a listener that can execute the logic you require and write results or changes back to the grid. You can create as many of these queries as desired and create chains. Similar to the "notification container" in gigaspaces. And as you would expect you can control the thread pools for this separately.

As for master worker pattern, you can configure client Ignite nodes to be written the the data and server nodes to store and process the data. You can even use other client nodes as remote listeners for data changes as you mentioned.